# What does the "uFlags &= ~CHN_PANNING" command do?

Tags: c++, c, flags

What does this command mean in a .c/.cpp file?

```
uFlags &= ~CHN_PANNING;
```

as per my research uFlags are Bit-Wise flags.

Comment: It unsets the `CHN_PANNING` flag if it was set.

Comment: I don't think this question is unclear or overly broad, and don't think it deserves this many downvotes. It might be "simple" but it's also a question that's hard to search for, and even though I'm sure it must be a duplicate I wasn't able to find one so far.

Comment: Agree that there are no good close votes, but this is not a novel question and the `~` operator is covered in early on any non-fraudulent text book. So no upvote. What prevents me from downvoting is `~` is next-to-impossible to Google, rendering the other Stack Overflow questions pretty much worthless unless you already know what `~` does. That dumps us back onto looking up the section on operators in a good reference book.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid, well written question within the scope of Stackoverflow. Just because it's a beginners question and easy to answer, doesn't make it bad. Maybe it is a duplicate, then mark it as such and link to the other question, but what is this nonsense about closing as off-topic, especially with that reason? Looking for an off-site resource? What? How did this happen? From users with so much rep and years being active even? Voted to reopen.

Comment: It's a common alternative to: `uFlags |= CHN_PANNING; uFlags ^= CHN_PANNING;` A good optimizer probably generates the same code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`~` is bit negation. It turns `011001` into `100110`, etc. If you `&` with the bit negation of a number, you essentially remove the `1`-bits of the right hand side from the bits on the left hand side (`1`s turn to `0`s after the bit negation and no bit can stay `1` if it's `&`-ed with `0`. `0`s turn to `1`s and `&`-ing with `1` doesn't change the original bit).

`bitset0 &=~ bitset1` (or `bitset0 &~ bitset`) is therefore a kind of a C/C++ idiom for (bit)set subtraction. It subtracts `bitset1` from `bitset0` (i.e. `bitset0 \ bitset1` in math notation), possibly (in the `=` version) assigning the result to `bitset0`.

Answer (score 3):

The *bitwise-AND assignment operator* `&=` gives to the expression

```
uFlags &= ~CHN_PANNING;
```

the same meaning as

```
uFlags = uFlags & ~CHN_PANNING;
```

Now, the `&` bit-wise operator is used to reset (clear) all those bits of flags to `0`, witch have the corresponding bit of the mask reset (cleared) to `0`. Other bits of flags remain unchanged.

For example:

```
  11001011  (flags)
&
  10101110  (mask)
-------------------
  10001010  (result)
```

Unary operator `~` is the negation - it switches bits with value `0` to `1` and vice versa. It means that your mask `~CHN_PANNING` will reset (clear) to `0` that bit (or those bits), which were set (to `1`) in the original `CHN_PANNING`.